# unable to "git push" to my own branch ? "remote contains work that you do not have locally"

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push new commits to my own separate branch that I've previously created with `git push origin myOwnBranchName`. I've already done a `git pull` and have compared my updated code with the recent commits from other contributors, their changes are all there. However, I still get this error every time I try to `git push origin myOwnBranchName`.

> "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
> not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
> to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
> (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again."

Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure `git pull` completes successfully? Can you try `git pull origin myOwnBranchName`?

Comment: I did `git pull "remote repo url"`, it asked me to enter message for merge and showed me the lines  of insertions/deletions that were made. What does `git pull origin myOwnBranchName` do that would be different? @Maroun

Comment: What you saw was the prompt to enter the message to create a merge commit. Did you complete the commit? (E.g. if you do `git log`, is the latest commit a merge commit?)

Comment: yes, there's a merge commit in the log @GoodDeeds

Comment: This tends to happen when you use `git rebase`. That is, over on `origin`, you had some commit(s) in your branch `br`. You then update some more-main-line branch and then `git checkout br` and `git rebase more-mainline-branch`, which copies your original commits to new and improved commits, dropping the originals in favor of the new ones. You then `git push origin br` and get this error, despite `br` being "your" (private) branch on `origin`, because you're asking the Git over on `origin` to drop *its* copies of your old commits in favor of the new and improved copies.

Comment: The *other* Git has no idea that this is what is going on. All it can tell is that someone is asking it to drop some precious commits. It says *no*. You can `git fetch origin` to make sure that nobody else has added commits to your branch, and having made sure of this, use any of the various forcing options (provided `origin` is set up to allow these) to tell it: *Yes, I know this drops some precious commits. That's fine, go ahead and drop them.*

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it's definitely possible that this happened as im still new to git and haven't always committed/pushed properly. I've never used `git rebase` though. Also, to be sure before i force, `git push origin myOwnBranch` wouldn't have any possibility of making changes to the main branch right? And will my previous commit history that is currently showing on the remote repo be deleted? @torek

Comment: Well, if you haven't run rebase, it wouldn't be a rebase ... unless you ran `git pull` and have `git pull` configured to run `git rebase`. :-)  (I generally suggest that newbies *avoid* `git pull`: break it into the two Git command that `git pull` runs for you, supposedly to make things convenient for you. Learn the separate commands first. Then, if you find it convenient, you'll be able to use `git pull` to run the two for you and still know what's going on. The two commands are `git fetch`, and then your choice of either `git merge` or `git rebase`.)

Comment: Anyway, the thing to know about `git push --force` (or any of its variants) is: this results in your Git *commanding*, rather than politely requesting, that the other Git set one of *its* branch names. The branch name you have it set is the same as with the non-force push. Branch names help Git (and you) *find* commits. As long as you're doing your push with the name `myOwnBranch`, that's the name you'll be asking or telling them to set. That means you will not affect their main branch.

Comment: maybe someone pushed into your branch their work

Comment: I will try a `git fetch`,  `git merge` and push afterwards. If fails ill probably do a force push. But will this delete my existing commit history on my remote branch? @torek

Comment: @Knightly: A force push to `myOwnBranch` on the remote named `origin` will (assuming `origin` *accepts* it) cause `origin`'s branch name `myOwnBranch` to find the commits that your local Git finds using your local Git's branch name `myOwnBranch`. Whether that "deletes [any] existing commit history" depends on what commits are findable now, vs what commits are findable after this push. The fact that you're getting this error indicates that, yes, it makes some currently findable commits (on `origin`) become unfindable (via name `myOwnBranch` on `origin`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `git fetch` first, usually it checks what updates in remotes exist. If it's not showing anything new try to run `git pull origin myOwnBranchName` and after that `git push origin myOwnBranchName`

Seems like your `git pull` not working because upstream not set in beginning.

Actually before starting to work on your branch run `git push --set-upstream origin your_branch_name`, after that you just run `git pull` and `git push` commands without setting origin

Comment: Before, I did `git pull "remote repo url"`, it asked me to enter message for merge and showed me the lines of insertions/deletions that were made. What does `git pull origin myOwnBranchName` do that would be different?

Comment: Can't understand what you currently asking for